# How to set image src to some "randomName.png" file available in current directory?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this scenario to reproduce an HTML implementation for 100+ images of **different names**.

myPackageDirectory
 - index.html
 - **some_name**.png
 - script/css files

Currently, I have to manually do the following

1. pick each image file from pool,
2. place it into the
   packageDirectory, then
3. rename it to static **img.png**, then
4. package(zip) the iteration.

I wish to skip renaming part from xyz.png --> img.png **by** something like 
`<img src="*.png" />` kind of thing. 
"**Client-side method**"

> I've used python to automate iterations, but 
>  am looking for some **html/js** way to pick file just by extension

Comment: or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511953/2996989)

Comment: @AhmedSunny — Your first comment links to a solution specific to SmartBear's TestComplete Desktop Application. It doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: @AhmedSunny — Your second comment links to a Node.js implementation, but the question says html/js which implies the JS is running client-side in the browser and not in Node.js.

Comment: sorry for that, i misread your question, but js and html are client side languages, and accessing directory and files on server you need server side language like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to obtain a list of file names on the server with the `.png` extension.

If your server allows directory listing, you can do this with client side JavaScript. Otherwise, you'll need a server side solution.

See the answers here: [Easiest way to get list of files in the server directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622369/easiest-way-to-get-list-of-files-in-the-server-directory)